# Python timer to spawn objects in animation?

Tags: python, animation

Is it possible to have objects spawn during an animation using python? I'm trying to spawn a steady flow of rigid bodies.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use particles?

Comment: Using animation features would probably be a better solution. Do you have some good reason to specifically use Python instead of anything else for this?

Comment: I'm looking for particle interaction so it doesn't seem to work. What would be another method without python?

Comment: Basically I want to fill a container with rigid bodies but have them fall into the container in a nice single file line.